# Wordpress how to use get_current_screen and global pagenow

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I do not understand the difference between the following two

> get_current_screen
>
> pagenow

Can you help me with that?

Comment: That function only works when used on the admin dashboard. From your code it seems you're trying to use it on the front-end, hence the reason why it returns `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`get_current_screen`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/#return):

> it'll "return current screen object or null when screen not defined".

If you want to use it to detect `admin pages`, then use a different hook, for example you could use `current_screen` hook:

```php
add_action('current_screen', 'detecting_current_screen');

function detecting_current_screen()
{
  $current_screen = get_current_screen();

  print_r($current_screen);
}
```

Or

```php
add_action('current_screen', 'detecting_current_screen');

function detecting_current_screen()
{
  global $current_screen;

  print_r($current_screen);
}
```

---

If you want to use it on the `client-side` and that returns null, then you could use a global variable called `$pagenow`.

**Note:** `$pagenow` will give you the template name.

```php
global $pagenow;

echo $pagenow;
```

Or

```php
echo $GLOBALS["pagenow"];
```

---

This should give you the name of the template you're on:

```php
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {

    global $pagenow;

    echo $pagenow;

}, 999 );
```

---

If none of the methods, mentioned above, work for you, then you could use another global variable called `$post`.

Or

You could check your page by using:

> [`get_page_by_title`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/)
> or
> [`get_page_by_path`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!
Yes, you are right, this was not a good method on the front.
$pagenow is a good function. but its return php file name . that's mean : 
 index.php

I realized that if I use $post global variable, I can understand the information on the front page .